# Oracle - estimate query tome run for alter table

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle19c

I run an alter table in Oracle 19c for table partition/sub-partition of millions of records. i would like to understand if before running the query is any possibility to have an approximate on how much time the operation will take.

Comment: No one, even DBMS, can know a runtime of any operation upfront. Because there are too much internal operations that have to be done and they don't have fixed runtime

Comment: Only experience and knowledge of your segment sizes can give you an idea before you even start. Once it starts, however, you can monitor `v$sql_plan_monitor` and watch the # of rows output from each step to calculate an estimate of how long before it completes. But to give you a ballpark idea, I regularly move partitions containing hundreds of millions of rows in just minutes. As long as you have the CPU resources, you can use a high DOP (e.g. `alter table x move partition y parallel (degree 32) update indexes`) to get the job done in a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: You should by the way edit your question to clarify what kind of alter you're talking about. Move? Split? Merge? There are many ways to alter an object but what it does under the covers can be vastly different depending on exactly what you're altering.